# Use Redis for caching Doctrine 2 queries and result in Symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, redis, doctrine-orm

I would like to use `Redis 6.0.1` in my `Symfony 5.0.8` project for caching `Doctrine 2` queries and result. I tried to configure Redis for Doctrine in `cache.yaml` and `doctrine.yaml` after added `predis/predis` package, but I'm not sure my configuration is correct.

`doctrine.yaml`:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                dbname: '%env(DATABASE_NAME)%'
                user: '%env(DATABASE_USER)%'
                password: '%env(DATABASE_PASSWORD)%'
                host: '%env(DATABASE_HOST)%'
                driver:  '%env(DATABASE_DRIVER)%'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App

        metadata_cache_driver: ~

        query_cache_driver:
            type: pool
            id: doctrine.query_cache_pool

        result_cache_driver:
            type: pool
            id: doctrine.result_cache_pool
```

`cache.yaml`:

```
framework:
    cache:
        # Redis
        app: cache.adapter.redis
        default_redis_provider: redis://localhost
```

Does my configuration for Redis seem correct to you? And how can I test if Redis works in my project?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

I finally succeeded, I give the solution for those who would be in the same case as me:

cache.yaml:

```
framework:
    cache:
        app: cache.adapter.redis
        default_redis_provider: "redis://%env(REDIS_HOST)%:%env(REDIS_PORT)%"

        pools:
            doctrine.result_cache_pool:
                adapter: cache.adapter.redis

            doctrine.system_cache_pool:
                adapter: cache.adapter.redis
```

doctrine.yaml:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                dbname: '%env(DATABASE_NAME)%'
                user: '%env(DATABASE_USER)%'
                password: '%env(DATABASE_PASSWORD)%'
                host: '%env(DATABASE_HOST)%'
                driver:  '%env(DATABASE_DRIVER)%'

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App

        metadata_cache_driver: ~

        query_cache_driver:
            type: pool
            pool: doctrine.system_cache_pool

        result_cache_driver:
            type: pool
            pool: doctrine.result_cache_pool
```

In a Doctrine Repository I created this function that I use in all repository functions:

```
protected function getQueryBuilder(): QueryBuilder
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('article')
                ->setCacheMode(Cache::MODE_NORMAL)
                ->setCacheable(true)
                ->setLifetime(300);
}
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  php:
    ...
    depends_on:
      - redis

  redis:
    image: redis:6.0.1
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    volumes:
      - ./docker/redis/redis.conf:/redis.conf
    command: [ "redis-server", "/redis.conf" ]
```

.env.local:

```
###> Redis ###
REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PORT=6379
###> Redis ###
```